# Class-Transformer: access request object or pass in additional metadata?

Tags: nestjs, class-transformer

I need to transform some file URL's in the response, the file paths need to contain the client id,

I have a shared class 'AssetReponseImagesDTO' this is used in lots of other classes, I need to transform the value of `filename` from a local path to append the CDN URL and client id and return a proper URL

I can get the CDN URL from the configService as it's just a string, to get the value of `ClientId` i have a custom decorator for nest.js - tried to use this decorator to access the same Id within the response but it doesn't work - seems to just return a string of the actual function

I also tried to create a new `ClientId` property on my top-level response DTO however the lower level Type such as `AssetResponseImagesDTO` won't have access to the parent's properties (unless I'm mistaken?)

Is there a way to pass in additional information to class-transformer which can then be referenced during the transform process?

```js
export class AssetResponseImagesDTO {
  @Expose({ name: 'url' })
  @Transform(({ value }) =>
    value ? `${configService.getCDNUrl()}${NEED_CLIENT_ID_HERE}}/asset/${value}` : null,
  )
  filename: string;

  @Expose()
  caption: string;

  @Expose({ name: 'link' })
  url: string;
}
```

**Updated for more detail**

**Top-level response DTO**

```js
export class NewVehicleDetailResponseWrapperDTO {
  @Type(() => NewVehicleResponseDTO)
  vehicle: NewVehicle;

  @Type(() => AssetResponseDTO)
  assets: Asset[];

  constructor(vehicle, assets) {
    this.vehicle = vehicle;
    this.assets = assets;
  }
}
```

**AssetResponseDTO**

```js
@Exclude()
export class AssetResponseDTO {
  @Expose({ name: 'type' })
  @Transform(({ value }) => AssetType[value])
  assetType: AssetType;

  @Expose({ name: 'name' })
  scrapName: string;

  @Expose({ name: 'images' })
  @Type(() => AssetResponseImagesDTO)
  assetImages: AssetImages[];

  @Expose({ name: 'snippet' })
  @Transform(({ value }) => value?.snippet)
  @Type(() => AssetSnippets)
  assetSnippet: AssetSnippets;

  @Expose({ name: 'content' })
  @Transform(({ value }) => value?.article)
  @Type(() => AssetContents)
  assetContent: AssetContents;
}
```

**ClientId Decorator**

```js
export const ClientId = createParamDecorator(
  (data: unknown, ctx: ExecutionContext) => {
    const request = ctx.switchToHttp().getRequest();

    // We need to set the clientId either via a query param or from the logged in user.
    let clientId;
    if (request.user.clientId) {
      clientId = request.user.clientId;
    }
    if (request.headers['x-client-id']) {
      clientId = request.headers['x-client-id'];
    }

    if (!clientId) {
      throw new BadRequestException();
    }

    return clientId;
  },
);
```

Comment: Can you please add your code of the ClientId decorator and the top level Dto?

Comment: Updated to show the `NewVehicleResponseWrapperDTO` -> `AssetResponseDTO` -> `AssetImageResponseDTO` and the ClientId decorator. The `AssetResponseDTO` is shared in many top-level wrapper DTO's